# CakePHP - Relationship Question - Posts.Child belongsTo User, How to define?

Tags: cakephp, children, belongs-to, posts

Below is a posts model, and as you can see I have a belongsTo relationship on each post, so that the user details are also retrieved with the post.
I would also like the exact same behaviour for the Posts.Children (see the hasMany definition below).

QUESTION:

How do I also apply the belongsTo relationship to the Posts.Children ( Posts.Child belongsTo User )??

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Post';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_owner',
          'fields' => array( "User.id" , "User.first_name" , "User.last_name" )
        )
    );

    // -=> 
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Child' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'conditions' => array( "Child.active" => "1" ),
        'limit' => '2',
        'order' => 'time DESC'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

And here is the PostsController Code which I am currently using:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {    
    var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
    var $name = 'Posts';

    function index() {
        $conditions = array( "Post.parent_id" => "0" , "Post.active" => "1" );
        $this->set(     'posts', $this->Post->find('all',array(   'conditions'=>$conditions     ))   );
        debug(   $this->Post->find('all',array(   'conditions'=>$conditions  ))   );
}
```

"what's the output if you call debug($this->Post->Child); in the posts controller?"
Here it is:

```
Post Object
(
    [name] => Post
    [hasMany] => Array
        (
            [Child] => Array
            (
                [className] => Post
                [foreignKey] => parent_id
                [conditions] => Array
                    (
                        [Child.active] => 1
                    )

                [fields] => 
                [order] => 
                [limit] => 
                [offset] => 
                [dependent] => 
                [exclusive] => 
                [finderQuery] => 
                [counterQuery] => 
            )

    )

[belongsTo] => Array
    (
        [User] => Array
            (
                [className] => User
                [foreignKey] => dom
                [fields] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => User.id
                        [1] => User.first_name
                        [2] => User.last_name
                    )

                [conditions] => 
                [order] => 
                [counterCache] => 
            )

    )

[useDbConfig] => default
[useTable] => posts
[displayField] => title
[id] => 
[data] => Array
    (
    )

[table] => posts
[primaryKey] => id
[_schema] => Array
    (
        [active] => Array
            (
                [type] => integer
                [null] => 
                [default] => 1
                [length] => 1
            )

        [id] => Array
            (
                [type] => integer
                [null] => 
                [default] => 
                [length] => 11
                [key] => primary
            )

        [parent_id] => Array
            (
                [type] => integer
                [null] => 
                [default] => 0
                [length] => 11
            )

        [time] => Array
            (
                [type] => integer
                [null] => 
                [default] => 0
                [length] => 11
            )

        [dom] => Array
            (
                [type] => integer
                [null] => 
                [default] => 
                [length] => 11
            )

        [sub] => Array
            (
                [type] => integer
                [null] => 
                [default] => 
                [length] => 11
            )

        [created] => Array
            (
                [type] => datetime
                [null] => 
                [default] => 
                [length] => 
            )

        [modified] => Array
            (
                [type] => datetime
                [null] => 
                [default] => 
                [length] => 
            )


        [text] => Array
            (
                [type] => string
                [null] => 
                [default] => 
                [length] => 4096
                [collate] => latin1_swedish_ci
                [charset] => latin1
            )

    )

[validate] => Array
    (
    )

[validationErrors] => Array
    (
    )

[tablePrefix] => 
[alias] => Child
[tableToModel] => Array
    (
        [posts] => Child
        [users] => User
    )

[logTransactions] => 
[cacheQueries] => 
[hasOne] => Array
    (
    )

[hasAndBelongsToMany] => Array
    (
    )

[actsAs] => 
[Behaviors] => BehaviorCollection Object
    (
        [modelName] => Child
        [_attached] => Array
            (
            )

        [_disabled] => Array
            (
            )

        [__methods] => Array
            (
            )

        [__mappedMethods] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[whitelist] => Array
    (
    )

[cacheSources] => 1
[findQueryType] => 
[recursive] => 1
[order] => 
[virtualFields] => Array
    (
    )

[__associationKeys] => Array
    (
        [belongsTo] => Array
            (
                [0] => className
                [1] => foreignKey
                [2] => conditions
                [3] => fields
                [4] => order
                [5] => counterCache
            )

        [hasOne] => Array
            (
                [0] => className
                [1] => foreignKey
                [2] => conditions
                [3] => fields
                [4] => order
                [5] => dependent
            )

        [hasMany] => Array
            (
                [0] => className
                [1] => foreignKey
                [2] => conditions
                [3] => fields
                [4] => order
                [5] => limit
                [6] => offset
                [7] => dependent
                [8] => exclusive
                [9] => finderQuery
                [10] => counterQuery
            )

        [hasAndBelongsToMany] => Array
            (
                [0] => className
                [1] => joinTable
                [2] => with
                [3] => foreignKey
                [4] => associationForeignKey
                [5] => conditions
                [6] => fields
                [7] => order
                [8] => limit
                [9] => offset
                [10] => unique
                [11] => finderQuery
                [12] => deleteQuery
                [13] => insertQuery
            )

    )

[__associations] => Array
    (
        [0] => belongsTo
        [1] => hasOne
        [2] => hasMany
        [3] => hasAndBelongsToMany
    )

[__backAssociation] => Array
    (
    )

[__insertID] => 
[__numRows] => 
[__affectedRows] => 
[_findMethods] => Array
    (
        [all] => 1
        [first] => 1
        [count] => 1
        [neighbors] => 1
        [list] => 1
        [threaded] => 1
    )

[User] => User Object
    (
        [name] => User
        [validate] => Array
            (
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [rule] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => minLength
                                [1] => 4
                            )

                        [message] => Name has to be at least four characters
                    )

                [email] => Array
                    (
                        [rule] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => email
                            )

                        [message] => Please enter a valid email
                    )

                [username] => Array
                    (
                        [Username has to be at least four characters] => Array
                            (
                                [rule] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => minLength
                                        [1] => 4
                                    )

                            )

                        [This username is already taken, please try another] => Array
                            (
                                [rule] => isUnique
                            )

                    )

                [password] => Array
                    (
                        [Password cannot be empty] => Array
                            (
                                [rule] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => notEmpty
                                    )

                            )

                        [Password must be at least four characters] => Array
                            (
                                [rule] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => minLength
                                        [1] => 4
                                    )

                            )

                        [Passwords must match] => Array
                            (
                                [rule] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => passwordCompare
                                        [1] => password_confirm
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [useDbConfig] => default
        [useTable] => users
        [displayField] => id
        [id] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
            )

        [table] => users
        [primaryKey] => id
        [_schema] => Array
            (
                [id] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => integer
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 11
                        [key] => primary
                    )

                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => boolean
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 1
                        [length] => 1
                    )

                [is_active] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => boolean
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 1
                        [length] => 1
                    )



                [gender] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => boolean
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 1
                        [length] => 1
                    )

                [first_name] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => string
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 200
                        [collate] => latin1_swedish_ci
                        [charset] => latin1
                    )

                [last_name] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => string
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 200
                        [collate] => latin1_swedish_ci
                        [charset] => latin1
                    )

                [email] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => string
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 200
                        [collate] => latin1_swedish_ci
                        [charset] => latin1
                    )

                [username] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => string
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 200
                        [collate] => latin1_swedish_ci
                        [charset] => latin1
                    )

                [password] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => string
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 200
                        [collate] => latin1_swedish_ci
                        [charset] => latin1
                    )

                [created] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => datetime
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 
                    )

                [modified] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => datetime
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 
                    )

                [bio] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => string
                        [null] => 
                        [default] => 
                        [length] => 2048
                        [collate] => latin1_swedish_ci
                        [charset] => latin1
                    )

            )

        [validationErrors] => Array
            (
            )

        [tablePrefix] => 
        [alias] => User
        [tableToModel] => Array
            (
                [users] => User
            )

        [logTransactions] => 
        [cacheQueries] => 
        [belongsTo] => Array
            (
            )

        [hasOne] => Array
            (
            )

        [hasMany] => Array
            (
            )

        [hasAndBelongsToMany] => Array
            (
            )

        [actsAs] => 
        [Behaviors] => BehaviorCollection Object
            (
                [modelName] => User
                [_attached] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_disabled] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [__methods] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [__mappedMethods] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [whitelist] => Array
            (
            )

        [cacheSources] => 1
        [findQueryType] => 
        [recursive] => 1
        [order] => 
        [virtualFields] => Array
            (
            )

        [__associationKeys] => Array
            (
                [belongsTo] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => className
                        [1] => foreignKey
                        [2] => conditions
                        [3] => fields
                        [4] => order
                        [5] => counterCache
                    )

                [hasOne] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => className
                        [1] => foreignKey
                        [2] => conditions
                        [3] => fields
                        [4] => order
                        [5] => dependent
                    )

                [hasMany] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => className
                        [1] => foreignKey
                        [2] => conditions
                        [3] => fields
                        [4] => order
                        [5] => limit
                        [6] => offset
                        [7] => dependent
                        [8] => exclusive
                        [9] => finderQuery
                        [10] => counterQuery
                    )

                [hasAndBelongsToMany] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => className
                        [1] => joinTable
                        [2] => with
                        [3] => foreignKey
                        [4] => associationForeignKey
                        [5] => conditions
                        [6] => fields
                        [7] => order
                        [8] => limit
                        [9] => offset
                        [10] => unique
                        [11] => finderQuery
                        [12] => deleteQuery
                        [13] => insertQuery
                    )

            )

        [__associations] => Array
            (
                [0] => belongsTo
                [1] => hasOne
                [2] => hasMany
                [3] => hasAndBelongsToMany
            )

        [__backAssociation] => Array
            (
            )

        [__insertID] => 
        [__numRows] => 
        [__affectedRows] => 
        [_findMethods] => Array
            (
                [all] => 1
                [first] => 1
                [count] => 1
                [neighbors] => 1
                [list] => 1
                [threaded] => 1
            )

        )

    [Child] => Post Object
 *RECURSION*
)
```

Comment: I am still looking for suggestions here guys. -> How do i get each post and each child of each post to display User Info? Each Post and each Child has an "owner" field, and I need to display the first_name and last_name of each post/child on that element in the view. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You put it in the `Children` model.

```
var $belongsTo = array( 'Post' );
```

By the way, what you posted is the model, not the controller. Hopefully it's just a typo and you have that in the correct place.

It's also unclear if you call the model "Child" or "Children". The `$hasMany` relationship is uses `Children`, but in the question you say `Posts.Child` -- do you have the inflection set up correctly?

EDIT: I may have misunderstood the question: if you want a hasMany relationship, you already have that. The problem is either in the way you retrieve the data or in the relationship definition.

Comment: Above is the Post Model. I dont have any other Models relating to Posts, should I have another seperate model for the children??

Comment: If you want to have the Children belongsTo Post relationship, then yes, you need the Children model. (What do you mean "not any other model relating to Posts"? You have the User model related, right?)

Comment: I currently have a User Model and a Post Model. The Post Model is above, and there is no mention of the Post Model in the User Model so far. I just want to be able to get access to  User.first_name and User.last_name  from within "app/views/posts/index.ctp

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to do anything, a Child is also a Post, so also belongsTo a User. (And you should name it "Child" not "Children")

With containable, try this: `$this->Post->find('all',array('contain'=>array('Child'=>array('User'))));`

Comment: Ok, thank you. But the DEBUG() is still only showing the User data for the Posts, and not for the children of each post.?? Sorry about this;)

Comment: Child does not seem to be regarded as a Post. Thanks for ur help;)

Comment: I see there's a User object in your Child object. Just make sure you have containable enabled and some correct data in the DB.