# CakePHP - Posts and Children Posts need User Data

Tags: cakephp

I have a Post Model, like this:

```
<?php
    class Post extends AppModel{
        var $name = 'Post';
        // -=> One Post hasMany Children [also of type Post, where Post.parent_id == foreignKey]:
        var $hasMany = array( 'Child' => array(            
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'conditions' => array( "Child.active" => "1" )    
        );

        var $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'dom',
            'fields' => array( "User.id" , "User.first_name" , "User.last_name" )
        )
    );

    }
?>
```

And a post_controller like this:

```
<?php
    class PostsController extends AppController {
        var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
        var $name = 'Posts';

        function index() {
            $conditions = array( "Post.parent_id" => "0" , "Post.active" => "1" );
                $this->set(     'posts', $this->Post->find('all',array(  'conditions'=>$conditions   ))   );
                debug(   $this->Post->find('all',array(   'conditions'=>$conditions    )    )   );
    }
    }

?>
```

And I want all posts to be dumped to the screen. A Post consists of 1 Post, and possibly multiple Child Posts, which are just Posts with a matching Post.parent_id.

I need User information (Users.first_name and Users.last_name etc) to accompany each Post AND each Child Post in the Posts View so that I may echo each Post and its children along with the name of the poster.

QUESTION:

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help guys....

Comment: you already posted a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983151/cakephp-relationship-question-posts-child-belongsto-user-how-to-define

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve data from your related objects:
i.g: to find the User who created a Post (in your posts controller):
(give $user_id the correct value, then:)
And then set the variable so the view can use it:

```
$post = $this->Post->User->findById($user_id);
$this->set('viewVariable', $post);
```

Using `debug($this->Post->User->findByWhateveryouwant);`
I think you will get by : )